Anonymous namespace to encourage inlining?
I've come across this single file algorithm for converting float to ASCII string, and what doesn't make sense to me is the comment at the top:
namespace { // anonymous namespace to encourage inlining

}

I've been reading that anonymous namespaces in a header file will make any functions in that namespace static, but what does it do to class definitions such as in this case? Why would wrapping something like this in an anonymous namespace "encourage" people to inline it?

Not people, the compiler

it doesnt do much to force coders to write definitions inline https://godbolt.org/z/xssxhnTj9

The idea is to make sure the functions in that namespace are not visible outside of the translation unit. Basically, a compiler has to make an actual function for things that could potentially be called from other source files -- because it only sees the file you're compiling at that moment, not all the files in the project. If a function is declared static, or invisible for other reasons, it knows that this can't happen.

@ChristianStieber How are you supposed to use this as is if it's in a .cpp file? I have to take it out of the namespace and put it in a header.

@Zebrafish you are using it in THAT cpp file only. Give it a named namespace (or none at all if that's your thing) if you put it in a header.

If you're asking how anonymous namespaces affect how people code, then you'll need to ask at https://psychology.stackexchange.com :)

@Zebrafish It's almost never correct to put an unnamed namespace in a header. The whole point of unnamed namespace is that the contents are only visible to the translation unit which contains it. If a function must be called from several different translation units (.cpp files), then it should be declared in a header, and cannot be in unnamed namespace.

Unnamed namespaces are a handy feature to give names internal linkage, which means that they only refer to something in the current translation unit. (By contrast, a name with external linkage refers to the same entity as the same name in any translation unit, and a name with no linkage never refers to the same entity as the same name anywhere else.)
But keep in mind that the linkage of a name is a design decision, not just a local optimisation convenience. Unnamed namespaces are a tool, but it's your responsibility to understand when and how to use it. The reason I would recommend unnamed namespaces is because I would keep names internal unless you know otherwise.
That said, the compiler knows that the entity named by an internal-linkage name cannot a priori be referenced by any other part of the program, which in turn allows a number of optimisations. Inlining the whole function body is one of them, but there are also things like (absence of) interposable references in the machine code or concerns about calling conventions.
There are multiple ways to give a name internal linkage, and you might see all of them in the wild. Sometimes you can avoid one of them if you already have an unnamed namespace providing the equivalent behaviour, or you can avoid the unnamed namespace if you already have internal linkage through other means:

Things inside an unnamed namespace generally have internal linkage.
Names declared at namespace scope with the static specifier.
Variables declared at namespace scope that are const qualified and do not have the extern specifier.


Why is inlining only a function that it does with internal linkage? Assume it doesn't have internal linkage, 1.c includes it, 2.c includes it, what does inlining have to do with a an optimisation it only does if it's static? Without static those c files refer to the same symbols as opposed to different ones, I don't see what difference it makes as to whether it inlines them. Do you mean in the case that it has internal linkage the compiler would hesitate to inline them because it would create multiple copies?

And what's the reasoning behind the semantics of having things inside an anonymous namespace have internal linkage? The idea is that anything inside a namespace, whether named or unnamed, is a different symbol, right? Unless it's inside the same namespace, or it's inside the same namespace but marked "static".
